# Call SOAP web services with parameter faced error code: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: web-services, soap, vbscript

I have developed a .vbs to call a SOAP web services as below. During execution, I get the error code 500. Please share your ideas if you faced this before.

I use Windows 7 to execute this file.

[image]

```
Dim dt
mydt = Now()
mm = add0( Month(mydt))
dd = add0( Day(mydt))
hh = add0( Hour(mydt))
mn = add0( Minute(mydt))
ss = add0( second(mydt))
'WScript.Echo (Year(mydt)) & mm & dd & hh & mm & ss
'short-name: Max 8 char
dt = mm & dd & hh & mm

Function add0 (testIn)
  Select Case Len(testIn) < 2
    Case True
      add0 = "0" & testIn
    Case Else
      add0 = testIn
  End Select
End Function
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

objStartFolder = "C:\test"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile In colFiles
  strFileName = objFile.Name
  If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "xml" Then
    strUrl = "http://IP:Server/dummy"
    strRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""" &_
                 " xmlns:v1=""http://crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/newbiz/newbusinessuploadreleaseservice/v1_0""" &_
                 " xmlns:v11=""http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0""" &_
                 " <soapenv:Header>/" &_
                 " <soapenv:Body>" &_
                 " <v1:new-business-upload-release-request>" &_
                 " <v1:new-business-upload-dto>" &_
                 " <v11:ID>ID="& dt &"</v11:ID>" &_
                 " <v11:file-name>"& objFile.Name &"</v11:file-name>" &_
                 " <v11:manual-upload>""false</v11:manual-upload>" &_
                 " <v11:auto-linking-enabled-flag>""true</v11:auto-linking-enabled-flag>" &_
                 " <v11:auto-merging-enabled-flag>""true</v11:auto-merging-enabled-flag>" &_
                 " <v11:strategy-option-choice>""USE_CREDITOR_DEFAULT_STRATEGY</v11:strategy-option-choice>" &_
                 " <v11:account-strategy-option-choice>""USE_CREDITOR_DEFAULT_STRATEGY</v11:account-strategy-option-choice>" &_
                 " <v11:auto-release>""true</v11:auto-release>" &_
                 " </v1:new-business-upload-dto>" &_
                 " <v1:web-service-request-version>""2</v1:web-service-request-version>" &_
                 " </v1:new-business-upload-release-request>" &_
                 "</soapenv:Body>" &_
                 "</soapenv:Envelope>"
  End If
Next
Dim http
Set http = createObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
http.Open "POST", strUrl, False
http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic 123"
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
http.send strRequest
If http.Status = 200 Then
  WScript.Echo "RESPONSE : " & http.responseXML.xml
Else
  WScript.Echo "ERRCODE : " & http.status
```

Comment: That `add0()` function is a lot of overhead for what should just equate to `mm = Right("00", & Month(mydt), 2)` etc.

Comment: In regard to the question a HTTP 500 error occurs when the server encounters an error, likely trying to parse your request. Just wondering what the `""` in a lot of your `<soapenv:Body>` elements is all about? I imagine the Web service is retrieving the request and getting a value like `"USE_CREDITOR_DEFAULT_STRATEGY` and wondering what to do with it or failing to de-serialise it and produces an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML data is invalid. The opening `<soapenv:Envelope>` tag is missing the closing angular bracket, and the end-slash for the tag `<soapenv:Header>` tag is after the closing angular bracket.

Change this:

```
strRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""" &_
             " xmlns:v1=""http://crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/newbiz/newbusinessuploadreleaseservice/v1_0""" &_
             " xmlns:v11=""http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0""" &_
             " <soapenv:Header>/" &_
             ...
```

into this:

```
strRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""" &_
             " xmlns:v1=""http://crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/newbiz/newbusinessuploadreleaseservice/v1_0""" &_
             " xmlns:v11=""http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0"">" &_
             " <soapenv:Header/>" &_
             ...
```

Also, you use `mm` twice in the construction of `dt`:

```
dt = mm & dd & hh & mm
```

It probably should be

```
dt = mm & dd & hh & mn
```

If that doesn't fix the problem you may need to check the webserver logs (error 500 is a server-side error) and/or consult the API documentation to verify that the request you're sending has the correct form.